# Cannot connect to Control Panel on CD server after configurating

Tags: sitecore-client, configuration

I have configured our CD Server by following the official spreadsheet obtained at https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/server_configuration_resources.

However, control panel is no longer available after configuration, showing "The requested document was not found" error message.

What I really want to do is to rebuild searching indexes on CD server so I need to access Control Panel. I am not sure which configuration file is causing this issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have followed that spreadsheet to configure the CD server, It has disabled the sitecore access since sitecore should be restricted on CD servers.

Now,to rebuild the indexes, You need to login to the CM server and rebuild the index 'Sitecore_web_index' from sitecore control panel of CM server.
That will rebuild the index on web database which your CD server is using.

Comment: But I removed all the configs related to web_index according to the official spread enable-disable sheet so now I cannot rebuild my sitecore_web_index. I assume I can only do that on CD server but it's not possible. How would you do that?

Comment: Depending on if you are using the shared Solr server, CM server should be held responsible for it and CD server should not have config files.if not you should have the configuration files on both the servers.I am not sure what configuration you are using but it looks like it is looking for the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.xxx.config files on CD server.You can manually copy those files on to CD server if it is failing.

Comment: I am using Azure Search this time. But keep getting "Could not find add method: AddIndex(type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration)" error from Indexing manager in CD server.

Comment: Do you have any custom index, if so you can try disabling it to see if it is working?

Comment: I figured out I had some extra indexes that shouldn't be there. Thanks for your help!